# Reactstrap: "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsx, reactstrap

I'm trying to make a faux shopping website for my React course and I keep getting the following message:

> Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (53:6)

Here's a look at the code that should, in theory, work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Producto from './Componentes/producto';
import './App.css';
import {Container} from 'reactstrap';
import {Row} from 'reactstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  return (
      {/* Plantilla para producto disponible en producto.js */}
        <Container>
          <Row>
              <Producto 
                titulo='Doom Eternal PS4' 
                imagen='https://www.weplay.cl/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/d406ac87fd7d160c9527a5559b847e93/p/s/ps4_doom-eternal.jpg' 
                descripcion='Los ejércitos del infierno han invadido la Tierra. Ponte en la piel del Slayer en una épica campaña para un jugador y cruza dimensiones para detener la destrucción definitiva de la humanidad.' 
                precio='666'
              />
              <Producto
                  titulo='Nintendo Switch'
                  imagen='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ivrWiYkLL._AC_.jpg'
                  descripcion='Consola Nintendo Switch Black'
                  precio='229.000'
              />
              <Producto
                titulo='Consola SONY PS4'
                imagen='https://estaticos.elperiodico.com/resources/jpg/9/8/playstation-sony-1370947347089.jpg'
                descripcion='Consola PS4 SLIM 500GB '
                precio='199.990'
              />
              <Producto
                titulo='Consola XBOX ONE'
                imagen='https://compass-ssl.xbox.com/assets/dd/2e/dd2ef163-a130-403a-a394-a5b11c1533c8.jpg?n=Xbox-Family_Image-0_X1S-1111_496x279.jpg'
                descripcion='Consola Xbox One solo juegos digitales '
                precio='229.000'
              />
              <Producto
                titulo='Consola New Nintendo 2DS'
                imagen='https://http2.mlstatic.com/nintendo-2ds-xl-black-and-turquoise-nuevo-D_NQ_NP_615117-MLM27995821063_082018-F.jpg'
                descripcion='2DS XL Black Turqoise'
                precio='129.990'
              />
              <Producto
                titulo='Big Chungus PS4'
                imagen='https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/big-chungus/images/7/7a/AB851D95-0AA6-496D-83FC-6616222C8F01.jpeg'
                descripcion='El videojuego más del mundo'
                precio='999.999.999'
              />
          </Row>
        </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Here's the GitHub repo, if anyone would like to run this locally.](https://github.com/ZGURemixer/carrito)

I've tried adding several different containers for the code such as
`<div>` and `<fragment>`, but none would work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned Your project and added one crucial thing. React [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), `shorter syntax` works perfectly fine  `<></>`.

**Example** in Your case:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Plantilla para producto disponible en producto.js */}
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Producto />
          <Producto />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.js** from Your repo.

```
import React from "react";
import Producto from "./Componentes/producto";
import "./App.css";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import { Row } from "reactstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Plantilla para producto disponible en producto.js */}
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Producto
            titulo="Doom Eternal PS4"
            imagen="https://www.weplay.cl/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/d406ac87fd7d160c9527a5559b847e93/p/s/ps4_doom-eternal.jpg"
            descripcion="Los ejércitos del infierno han invadido la Tierra. Ponte en la piel del Slayer en una épica campaña para un jugador y cruza dimensiones para detener la destrucción definitiva de la humanidad."
            precio="666"
          />
          <Producto
            titulo="Nintendo Switch"
            imagen="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ivrWiYkLL._AC_.jpg"
            descripcion="Consola Nintendo Switch Black"
            precio="229.000"
          />
          <Producto
            titulo="Consola SONY PS4"
            imagen="https://estaticos.elperiodico.com/resources/jpg/9/8/playstation-sony-1370947347089.jpg"
            descripcion="Consola PS4 SLIM 500GB "
            precio="199.990"
          />
          <Producto
            titulo="Consola XBOX ONE"
            imagen="https://compass-ssl.xbox.com/assets/dd/2e/dd2ef163-a130-403a-a394-a5b11c1533c8.jpg?n=Xbox-Family_Image-0_X1S-1111_496x279.jpg"
            descripcion="Consola Xbox One solo juegos digitales "
            precio="229.000"
          />
          <Producto
            titulo="Consola New Nintendo 2DS"
            imagen="https://http2.mlstatic.com/nintendo-2ds-xl-black-and-turquoise-nuevo-D_NQ_NP_615117-MLM27995821063_082018-F.jpg"
            descripcion="2DS XL Black Turqoise"
            precio="129.990"
          />
          <Producto
            titulo="Big Chungus PS4"
            imagen="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/big-chungus/images/7/7a/AB851D95-0AA6-496D-83FC-6616222C8F01.jpeg"
            descripcion="El videojuego más del mundo"
            precio="999.999.999"
          />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

**Output in VScode** `terminal`

[image]

---

**Output in browser** (`console`). *I blurred the images for obvious reasons*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The comment above the  tag is considered to be its own JSX element, because it's enclosed with curly braces. Move it one line below and it will work fine!

```
<Container>
{/* Plantilla para producto disponible en producto.js */}
```